# how Retrieve video from Firebase Storage? kotlin

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

how can I upload a video hosted in firebase to a videoview?

```
var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("videos/$recivir.mp4")
val mediaController = MediaController(this)
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
```

Comment: I have added an asnwer, please have a check. Don't forget to upvote or verify if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation about how to download files with Cloud Storage on Android here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_files, you can download the media (your video) using `getBytes()`, `getStream()`, or `getDownloadUrl()`, depends on what format you want to use.

You can use `getDownloadUrl()` to get the url of the video in Firebase Storage and set the url into the video view.

```kotlin
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
    videoView.setVideoPath(it); // "it" is the url of the video from Firebase Firestore
    videoView.start();
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Handle any errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

progressDialog.show()

```
    //timestamp
    val timestamp = ""+System.currentTimeMillis()

    //file path and name in firebase storage
    val filePathAndName = "Videos/video_$timestamp"

    //storage reference
    val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName)
    //upload video using uri of video to storage
    storageReference.putFile(videoUri!!)
        .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
             //uploaded,get url of uploaded video
            val uriTask = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful);
            val downloadUri = uriTask.result
            if (uriTask.isSuccessful){
                //video url is received successfully

                //now we can add video details to firebase db
                val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                hashMap["id"] = "$timestamp"
                hashMap["title"] = "$title"
                hashMap["timestamp"] = "$timestamp"
                hashMap["videoUri"] = "$downloadUri"

                //put the above info to db
                val dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Videos")
                dbReference.child(timestamp)
                    .setValue(hashMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                        //video info added successfully
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Video Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        //failed adding video info
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(this,"${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            //failed uploading
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(this,"${e.message}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).